# Illusion of multithreading in Javascript application

Tags: javascript

I know multithreading is not possible in javascript but I am trying to give a illusion of different functions running independently for instance. In my code I have 3 simple functions.

```
var input1 = [10,6,5,2,6,5];
var input2 = [3,4,8,7,1,9];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var sum = 0;


for(i = 0; i<6; i++){
  x = input1[i];
  y = input2[i];
  getInput(x,y);
}

function getInput(a,b){
  x = a;
  y = b;
  getSum(x,y);
}

function getSum(j,k){
  sum = j + k;
  printSum(sum);
}

function printSum(i){
  alert(i);
}
```

The purpose of getInput function should be to get x and y input and pass it to the getSum function. It should not wait for getSum and other functions to finish before getting the next pair of input. This applies for all the other functions. They should all operate independently like a clock. Now I know js i singlethreaded but i was wondering if it is possible to design a loop to give this illusion. Here is my current [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t6nxmz4L/). Please advice.

Comment: Multi-threading is "possible" if you create a webworker.

Comment: @SterlingArcher is it possible to show a small demo ? I have heard of webworker so i am guessing in my case i would put my 3 functions in 3 different scripts and declare them as 3 different workers? Also is it possible to design a for loop somehow to give this illusion?

Comment: A for loop will block the UI, so no. You could probably create the illusion of threads using timeouts, but why fake it when you can use workers? Posted an answer with a cheese demo and links to more info.

Comment: @ChrisBaker thank you for the demo, i was wondering as i am still trying to understand this is it possible to show how i can utilize it for the example i posted

Comment: Spawn new workers within the loop. Your example doesn't lend itself to demonstration of web workers very well because a) you're using `alert`, which is blocking, and b) the work being done in each function is so trivial that you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between synch and asynch execution. There are demonstrations in the articles I linked to, and at the library I linked to.  Rather than using my time to write still more demonstration code, you should use your own time to learn how to do this using the examples I linked to, and get experience implementing it in your real code :)

Comment: @ChrisBaker makes sense and i was wondering how setTimeout would also help me create an illusion. would all 3 of the functions be called every 3 seconds or something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to create the illusion, you can use WebWorkers to get the real thing.

On your main page:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from worker', e.data);
};
myWorker.postMessage('some variable')
```

... worker.js:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  var workerResult = 'Variable: ' + (e.data);
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

Example from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

You can read more at: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

There are several libraries available as well, one of which is [multithread.js](https://keithwhor.github.io/multithread.js/)